# Order dependent types

Tags: c#

I have a creative question. I want to give types an order which is dependent on dependencies. :)

Example:

```
public class Oil
{}

public class Seat
{}

public class Wheel : IDependOn<Oil>
{}

public class Car : IDependOn<Wheel>, IDependOn<Seat>
{}
```

So, and now I want to have function (including reflection) which gives me back a `Dictionary<Int32, Type>` where the `Int32` index is the order.

The function definition will look like:

```
public Dictionary<Int32, Type> GetOrderedTypes(List<Type> types);
```

The result for this example should be:

```
<1, Oil>
<2, Seat>
<3, Wheel>
<4, Car>
```

The tasks can be much more complex, but will have ever the same logic.

- Types with no dependencies have the lowest order.
- For types with the same dependencies the order is not important.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: To get you started, try searching for "topological sort".

Comment: Why would you use a dictionary instead of a list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort depended objects by dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106862/how-to-sort-depended-objects-by-dependency)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/03/16/90851.aspx is a nice introduction to topo sorting. The code is JavaScript but it is not too hard to translate to c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
interface IDependOn<T> { }

class Oil { }

class Seat { }

class Wheel : IDependOn<Oil> { }

class Car : IDependOn<Wheel>, IDependOn<Oil> { }

static class TypeExtensions {

  public static IEnumerable<Type> OrderByDependencies(this IEnumerable<Type> types) {
    if (types == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
    var dictionary = types.ToDictionary(t => t, t => GetDependOnTypes(t));
    var list = dictionary
      .Where(kvp => !kvp.Value.Any())
      .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
      .ToList();
    foreach (var type in list)
      dictionary.Remove(type);
    foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary.Where(kvp => !kvp.Value.Any())) {
      list.Add(keyValuePair.Key);
      dictionary.Remove(keyValuePair.Key);
    }
    while (dictionary.Count > 0) {
      var type = dictionary.Keys.First();
      Recurse(type, dictionary, list);
    }
    return list;
  }

  static void Recurse(Type type, Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Type>> dictionary, List<Type> list) {
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(type))
      return;
    foreach (var dependOnType in dictionary[type])
      Recurse(dependOnType, dictionary, list);
    list.Add(type);
    dictionary.Remove(type);
  }

  static IEnumerable<Type> GetDependOnTypes(Type type) {
    return type
      .GetInterfaces()
      .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDependOn<>))
      .Select(i => i.GetGenericArguments().First());
  }

}
```

You can create an ordered list like this:

```
var orderedList =
  new[] { typeof(Oil), typeof(Seat), typeof(Wheel), typeof(Car) }
    .OrderByDependencies();
```

If you want a dictionary with indices as keys you can easily create it from the ordered list.

Comment: So, I tested it, but it doesen't work if I shuffle the types like this:

var orderedList = new[] { typeof(Car), typeof(Wheel), typeof(Oil), typeof(Seat) };

Comment: @ChristianNeuß: My solution only orders by dependencies. However, I have noted that you have the added requirement that types with no dependencies should come first. I have updated my answer to always put these types first.