# Sort .NET Assemblies by dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a set of .NET assemblies within my project. I wish to sort them by their dependencies.

So if I have (for example):

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> unsorted = LoadAssembliesFromFolder();
```

I want to be able to call:

```
var IEnumerable<Assembly> sorted = unsorted.SortByDependency();
```

In reality, the resultant set would hopefully end up looking like the project build order dialog in Visual Studio.

Any thoughts? I don't really want to go down an iterative approach which could take quite some time.

Cheers

Comment: I don't think there is another way than iterative here.

Comment: Do you need an algorithm ?

Comment: How do you want to deal with circular references? (e.g. `System` and `System.Xml` in the framework reference each other)

Comment: Good question - I don't need to sort system libraries, only my own, but I suspect that in my set of libraries, circular references only exist at the same 'level' of library (i.e. a similar set of dependencies) meaning that the order between the two is not important.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to levarage the `GetReferencedAssemblies()` method of `Assembly`. This returns a list of `AssemblyName` values and allows you to load the next assembly. Please note that this causes every assembly to be loaded into memory. Once loaded, assemblies can't be unloaded.

```
class AssemblyReferenceComparison : IComparer<Assembly>
{
    public int Compare(Assembly x, Assembly y)
    {
        if (x == y) return 0;
        if (GetReferencesAssemblies(x).Contains(y)) return -1;
        if (GetReferencesAssemblies(y).Contains(x)) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetReferencesAssemblies(Assembly a)
    {
        var referencedAssemblies = new HashSet<Assembly>();
        FillReferencesAssemblies(a, referencedAssemblies);
        return referencedAssemblies;
    }

    private static void FillReferencesAssemblies(Assembly a, HashSet<Assembly> referencedAssemblies)
    {
        referencedAssemblies.Add(a);

        var directAssemblies = a.GetReferencedAssemblies()
            .Select(name => Load(name))
            .Where(asm => asm != null)
            .Where(asm => !referencedAssemblies.Contains(asm))
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var directAssembly in directAssemblies)
        {
            FillReferencesAssemblies(directAssembly, referencedAssemblies);
        }
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    private static Assembly Load(AssemblyName name)
    {
        try { return Assembly.Load(name); }
        catch { return null; }
    }
}
```

To use:

```
var assemblies = LoadAssembliesFromFolder()
    .OrderBy(a => a, new AssemblyReferenceComparison())
    .ThenBy(a => a.FullName);
```

Comment: nice answer and it should be marked

Answer (score 0):

I found @Steven's answer too slow so I have come up with the following:

```
public class AssemblyItem {
    public Assembly Item { get; set; }
    public IList<AssemblyItem> Dependencies { get; set; }

    public AssemblyItem(Assembly item) {
        Item = item;
        Dependencies = new List<AssemblyItem>();
    }
}

public static void Main() {
    // Get the assemblies
    var assemblyItems = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().OrderBy(a => a.FullName).Select(a => new AssemblyItem(a)).ToList();

    // Add the dependencies
    foreach (var item in assemblyItems) {
        foreach (var reference in item.Item.GetReferencedAssemblies()) {
            var dependency = assemblyItems.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Item.FullName == reference.FullName);

            if (dependency != null)
                item.Dependencies.Add(dependency);
        }
    }

    // Sort the assemblies
    var sortedAssemblyItems = assemblyItems.TSort(i => i.Dependencies);
}
```

It uses the TSort extension method from:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027096/155899

For more information on how this works see the following article on Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like :

```
public class AssemblyInfo
{
    public readonly Assembly Item;
    public readonly IList<AssemblyInfo> ReferencedAssemblies;

    public AssemblyInfo(Assembly item)
    {
        Item = item ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Item is null");
        ReferencedAssemblies = new List<AssemblyInfo>();
    }

    int Count()
    {
        return ReferencedAssemblies.Count;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Item.FullName;
    }

    public IEnumerable<AssemblyInfo> OrderedDependencies()
    {
        List<AssemblyInfo> localOrdered = new List<AssemblyInfo>();
        foreach (AssemblyInfo item in ReferencedAssemblies.OrderBy(t => t.Count()))
        {
            IEnumerable<AssemblyInfo> temp = item.OrderedDependencies();
            localOrdered = localOrdered.Union<AssemblyInfo>(temp).ToList();
        }
        localOrdered.Add(this);
        return localOrdered;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return Item.FullName.Equals(((AssemblyInfo)obj).Item.FullName);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        return Item.FullName.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static AssemblyInfo Parse(string assembliesPath, string assemblyName)
    {
        return Parse(assembliesPath, assemblyName, new Dictionary<string, Assembly>());
    }
    static AssemblyInfo Parse(string assembliesPath, string assemblyName, Dictionary<string, Assembly> loadedAssemblies)
    {
        string assemblyFullPath = Path.Combine(assembliesPath, assemblyName);
        if (!File.Exists(assemblyFullPath))
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (loadedAssemblies == null)
        {
            loadedAssemblies = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();
        }
        if (!loadedAssemblies.ContainsKey(assemblyFullPath))
        {
            loadedAssemblies.Add(assemblyFullPath, Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyFullPath)));
        }

        Assembly a = loadedAssemblies[assemblyFullPath];
        AssemblyInfo ai = new AssemblyInfo(a);
        foreach (AssemblyName an in a.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            AssemblyInfo d = Parse(assembliesPath, an.Name + ".dll", loadedAssemblies);
            if (d != null)
            {
                ai.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(d);
            }
        }
        return ai;
    }
}
```

Use it :

```
AssemblyInfo ai = AssemblyInfo.Parse("assembliesPath","yourassembly.dll");
IEnumerable<AssemblyInfo> sorted = ai.OrderedDependencies();
foreach (AssemblyInfo item in sorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item.ManifestModule.ToString());
}
```