# Order List By Dependencies

Tags: c#, sorting, compare

Given the following list:

```
var modules = new List<Module>() {
    new Module() { Name = "Audits", Dependencies = new[] { "Logs" } },
    new Module() { Name = "Blog", Dependencies = new[] { "Content", "Tags" } },
    new Module() { Name = "Content", Dependencies = new[] { "Audits" } },
    new Module() { Name = "Logs" },
    new Module() { Name = "Tags" }
};
```

I need to create a way to order this list programmatically so that the modules that are most-dependable are at the top. Therefore the desired order using the above example would be:

1. Logs
2. Audits
3. Content
4. Tags
5. Blog

Since "Content" has a dependency on "Audits" then "Audits" appears first. But since "Audits" has a dependency on "Logs" then "Logs" comes above "Audits" and so. "Blog" appears last since it has dependencies on both "Content" and "Tags" and therefore they come above.

I hope I've described my problem clear enough. I'm sure there's some clever algorithm to handle this and make it as efficient as possible but it's alluded me so far. I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are describing is called [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort): given a partial ordering, try to find a linear description that respects that ordering.

The typical algorithm to solve this problem takes `O(|V| + |E|)` time, where `|V|` is the number of vertices (modules in your example) and `|E|` is the number of edges (dependencies in your example).

The linked Wikipedia article also provides [pseudo code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort#Algorithms). It will take some book keeping to convert the algorithm to your example, but it is relatively straightforward.

Comment: I used the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11027096/155899 for the code but thanks for giving me the name of the algorithm so that I could search for the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a comparison function between values that sorts based on dependencies

```
static int CompareModules(Module left, Module right) { 
  if (left.Dependencies.Contains(right.Name)) { 
    return 1;
  }

  if (right.Dependencies.Contains(left.Name)) { 
    return -1;
  }

  return left.Dependencies.Length - right.Dependencies.Length;
}
```

Then use this as the argument to `List<T>.Sort`

```
modules.Sort(CompareModules);
```

Note that this sample has the assumptions that `Dependencies` is an empty array when their are no dependencies and that there are no circular dependencies

Comment: This doesn't take transitive dependencies into account, which, depending on the sort implementation, will lead to incorrect results, or even an infinite loop.