# Sort list of tables to reference properly when create multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server

Let say that I have a list of tables to create and some of them reference to others (within the table list). So I looped each table and find tables that it reference to, then move them to the top of the list in order to create them first. To be specific:

```
List<string> lstTemp = new List<string>(listTables);
foreach (string table in lstTemp)
{
    foreach (string tbl in GetReferenceTablesOf(table))
    {
        int index = lstTemp.IndexOf(tbl);
        listTables.Move(index, 0);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when there are many tables reference to others, the list's order is not what I wanted. For example, table B reference to table A, so table A will be moved to the top of the list (index = 0), but after serveral loops, table B moved to the top due to other tables reference to table B too and causes error when I execute 'alter table add constraint...' query.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: if you use the SMO sql server objects and loop over the tables then you can check each tables' dependencies instead of looping through string table names

Comment: it's just a demo for my question, not the real code.

Comment: well then you should be able to cast the dependencies that to table, if succesfully converted to table then iterate through dependency tables and remove them before the original table

Comment: This is called Topological Sort, solution in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106862/how-to-sort-depended-objects-by-dependency

Comment: thank Eric, this is likely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create all tables first in any order without any references (foreign keys etc.). Once all tables are created, then create all references any order you want.

Comment: this is not possible because beside creating tables, I also use that table list to insert or update records. therefore sorting table list is essential.

Comment: maybe you should look at building a tree dependency, just be careful for circular references.