# c# DFS topological sort of directed graph using adjacency list

Tags: c#, graph, depth-first-search, adjacency-list, topological-sort

I am trying to accomplish a topological sort on the following graph (pulled from The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena).
[Graph to be Sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMmDu.png) The answer according to the [book](http://www.algorist.com/algowiki/index.php/TADM2E_5.2) is H, A, B, D, E, G, I, J, C, F but I keep getting A, B, D, E, C, F, H, G, I, J.

I don't understand how H can go to the front when a topological sort means that a start node, with a directed edge to a destination node, should come first. Is the answer given in the book achievable or even correct?
Is a topological sort possible with this kind of graph (because it is not acyclic)?
Below is the generic graph using adjacency list

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
    public LinkedList<Node<T>> Adjacent { get; set; }

    public Node(T _id)
    {
        this.Id = _id;
        this.Adjacent = new LinkedList<Node<T>>();
    }
}

public class Graph<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, Node<T>> nodeLookup = new Dictionary<T, Node<T>>();

    public Node<T> GetNode(T id)
    {
        if (!nodeLookup.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            Node<T> s = new Node<T>(id);
            nodeLookup.Add(id, s);
        }

        return nodeLookup.Single(x => x.Key.ToString() == id.ToString()).Value;
    }

    public void AddEdgeDirected(T source, T destination)
    {
        Node<T> s = GetNode(source);
        Node<T> d = GetNode(destination);

        s.Adjacent.AddLast(d);
    }

    public void PrintGraph()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------- Print Graph");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<T, Node<T>> kvp in nodeLookup)
        {
            Node<T> val = kvp.Value;
            Console.Write($"[{val.Id}]: ");
            foreach (Node<T> adj in val.Adjacent)
            {
                Console.Write($"-> {adj.Id}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public List<Node<T>> GetAllVertices()
    {
        List<Node<T>> result = new List<Node<T>>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<T, Node<T>> kvp in nodeLookup)
        {
            result.Add(kvp.Value);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Below is the sorting algorithm which prints out the sorted list. It uses a HashSet to find if the node has been visited and uses an array to insert the nodes Id once there are no more nodes to visit. 
It uses recursion in the DFSTopSortUtil to get the index to insert the node key in the correct spot in the result array.

```
public static class TopologicalSort<T>
{
    public static void DFSTopSort(Graph<T> graph)
    {
        List<Node<T>> vertices = graph.GetAllVertices();
        int numVertices = graph.GetAllVertices().Count;
        HashSet<T> visited = new HashSet<T>();
        T[] result = new T[numVertices];
        int n = numVertices - 1; //largest topNum  

        foreach (Node<T> node in vertices)
        {
            if (!visited.Contains(node.Id))
            {
                n = DFSTopSortUtil(node, visited, result, n, vertices);
            }
        }

        Console.Write("\nTopSort_03 - Print: ");
        Console.Write("\n\t");
        result.Reverse();
        foreach (T val in result)
        {
            Console.Write($"->{val}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static int DFSTopSortUtil(Node<T> node, HashSet<T> visited, T[] result, int n, List<Node<T>> vertices)
    {
        visited.Add(node.Id);

        foreach (Node<T> child in node.Adjacent)
        {
            if (!visited.Contains(child.Id))
            {
                n = DFSTopSortUtil(child, visited, result, n, vertices);
            }
        }
        result[n] = node.Id;
        return n - 1;
    }
}
```

And here is the main method and the graph creation

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Graph<string> graph = new Graph<string>();
        AutoCreateGraph_TopSort_Directed(graph);
        graph.PrintGraph();
        TopologicalSort<string>.DFSTopSort(graph);
    }

    public static void AutoCreateGraph_TopSort_Directed(Graph<string> graph)
    {
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("A", "B");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("B", "C");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("C", "F");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("F", "H");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("H", "G");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("G", "F");

        graph.AddEdgeDirected("G", "I");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("I", "J");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("H", "J");

        graph.AddEdgeDirected("B", "E");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("E", "C");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("E", "F");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("E", "G");

        graph.AddEdgeDirected("B", "D");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("D", "E");
        graph.AddEdgeDirected("D", "G");

        graph.AddEdgeDirected("A", "D");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly your traversal code is wrong. I suggest taking a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106862/how-to-sort-depended-objects-by-dependency/